# Joining array elements with a delimiter except last element

Tags: ruby, arrays

How would I go about joining Array elements (manually, without using [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) or similar methods) with a delimiter without printing the delimiter after the last element?

**Example:**

```
names = %w[Benny Punky Jess]

for n in names
  # apply logic
end

# OUTPUT => "Benny_Punky_Jess"
```

This is for the purpose of learning and is not related to homework. A non-language specific  answer is preferred, as I want to be able to apply this logic in other places as well.

Comment: -1 
Why would you not want to use `join` when it does exactly what you want?

Comment: If you actually read the question, you would see it is for learning purposes. I am interested in the process, not the end-result.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please select the one that was most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
names = %w[Benny Punky Jess]
output = ''
for n in names
  if output.blank?
    output = n
  else
    output += '_' << n
  end
end
p output
```

Comment: Of the three answers (so far) this is my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
output = "";
DELIMITER = ",";
for (i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
 output += array[i] + DELIMITER; 
}
output += array[array.length-1];
```

In ruby, you can use `.each_with_index` and check whether the index corresponds to the array length, and then not append the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do,

```
names = %w[Benny Punky Jess]
output = ""
for n in names
   output = output + n
   output = output + '_' unless (n.eql? names[-1])
end
puts output
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ["Benny", "Punky", "Jess"].reduce { |str,s| str + '_' + s }
  #=> "Benny_Punky_Jess"
```

The key is to use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`) without an argument, so that `str` is initially `'Benny'` and the first element of `names` passed to the block is `'Punky'`.

Comment: Krystah, I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
names = %w[Benny Punky Jess]
output = ""
names.each { |n| !(n.eql? names[-1]) ? output << n << '_' : output << n }
puts output
```